# is it possible to overwrite a error or success message generated by the magento?

Tags: magento

Is it possible to overwrite a error/success message generated by the magento system?

For example if we add a product the success message is
"Laptop is added to your cart..!", what if i would like to add my client's name like "Josh you had added Laptop to your cart"

Thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy enough to add your custom message to the stack when an item is added. Add an event listener for `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` which does this:

```
public function observeAddToCart($observer) { 
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct(); // you may need to play with this
    $session = Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->addSuccess($message); 
    $message = Mage::helper("yourmodule")->__('%s, you added %s to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getName()));
    $session->addSuccess($message); 
}
```

That leaves the problem of removing the old message. The closest that I see right now is that you can clear all other messages on command by retrieving them. So you could clear the Magento-set message afterwards like so:

```
Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->getMessages(true);
```

You would need to do this after Magento's message has been added, however. Hope that gives you a start!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: @Joseph, i have a collection of videos related to a category, that category does not have any product due to which it displays a message "There are no products matching the selection." how could i remove this?
i had tried 'Mage::getSingleton("core(&)catalog/session")->getMessages(true);' but of no use.

Comment: @user8009 this is an answer from 2011, you're best off asking a new question :)

Answer (score 4):

I've written a helper function that allows you to search for a specific message with an option to remove if found.  It's a bit disappointing this isn't available in core..

```
/**
 * Searches messages for @param $string.
 * Will remove the message if $remove is true.
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @param boolean $remove: false
 * @param string $which: core/session
 * @return true|false, found|not found
 * @access public
 */
public function message_search( $string, $remove = false, $which = 'core/session' ) {

  $found = false;

  $messages = Mage::getSingleton( $which )->getMessages();
  foreach( $messages->getItems() as $message )
    if( stristr( $message->getText(), $string ) ) {
      $found = true;
      if( $remove ) $message->setIdentifier( 'this_message_will_be_removed' );
    }

  if( $remove ) $messages->deleteMessageByIdentifier( 'this_message_will_be_removed' );
  return $found;

}
```